# How to access the adjacent cells of each elements of matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, implementation

Here two cells are considered adjacent if they share a boundary. 
For example :

```
A = 5 6 4
    2 1 3
    7 9 8
```

Here adjacent elements to index 0,0 is at index [0,1] and [1,0] and for index 1,1 the adjacent elements are at index [0,1],[1,0],[2,1] and [1,2].

Comment: You did not mention what datatype you are using. List of lists? Numpy array? Dataframe

Comment: It is list of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposed you have `m`x`n` matrix, and you want to find the adjacent indices of the cell (`i`, `j`):

```
def get_adjacent_indices(i, j, m, n):
   adjacent_indices = []
    if i > 0:
        adjacent_indices.append((i-1,j))
    if i+1 < m:
        adjacent_indices.append((i+1,j))
    if j > 0:
        adjacent_indices.append((i,j-1))
    if j+1 < n:
        adjacent_indices.append((i,j+1))
    return adjacent_indices
```

Comment: What if you also want to include the diagonally adjacent cells? This would create 8 if statements if i'm not mistaken. Could that be written more easily?

Answer (score 3):

To also check for diagonals, regarding what *Casper Dijkstrao* asked, I usually write some code like this:

```
def adj_finder(matrix, position):
    adj = []
    
    for dx in range(-1, 2):
        for dy in range(-1, 2):
            rangeX = range(0, matrix.shape[0])  # X bounds
            rangeY = range(0, matrix.shape[1])  # Y bounds
            
            (newX, newY) = (position[0]+dx, position[1]+dy)  # adjacent cell
            
            if (newX in rangeX) and (newY in rangeY) and (dx, dy) != (0, 0):
                adj.append((newX, newY))
    
    return adj
```

> The function gets the `matrix` argument to extract the size of its row and column (I use `numpy`, so `matrix.shape` returns `(row_size, column_size)` tuple).
>
> It also gets the current cell as `pointer` argument (it's like `(X,Y)`).
>
> Then It generate adjacent cells, and if they were legit (*1. they were not out of the bound*, and *2. not identical to reference position*), it adds them to adjacent list, `adj`.

I'd like to emphasize that using the above algorithm, you can easily obtain neighbors in farther distances as well. Just modify the range in the for loops, like this:

```
for v in range(0-distance, 1+distance):
    for h in range(0-distance, 1+distance):
        ...
```

> Where `distance` is the maximum distance of adjacent you want to let in.

Answer (score 1):

This will be another way - prob. involve some math tricks or regarded more concise (if you're *more math-inclined) :*

```
def neighbours(grid, r, c):
    vals = sum((row[c -(c>0): c+2]
                for row in grid[r -(r>0):r+2]), [])
    vals.remove(grid[r][c])     # rm itself.
    return vals       


grid = [[1, 5, 4, 9], 
        [2, 8, 3, 8], 
        [6, 3, 6, 3], 
        [7, 4, 7, 1]]
```

Outputs:  (all items are in order)

```
print(f' {neighbours(grid, 2, 2)} ') # [8, 3, 8, 3, 3, 4, 7, 1] 
print(f' {neighbours(grid, 0, 0)} ') # [5, 2, 8] 
print(f' {neighbours(grid, 1, 1)} ') # [[1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6]
```

Comment: This is not a `pythonic way`. PEP 20 - first three items: Beautiful is better than ugly (your code - NO). Explicit is better than implicit (your code - NO). Simple is better than complex (your code - NO).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with and without comments.
My answer may not be as clean as the other replies.
But I like the modularity of this approach.

### With comments

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal

def get_adjacent_indices(input_list:list, index_y:int, index_x:int, return_as:Literal['index', 'value']='index') -> list:
    """Get the adjacent indices of the given index in the given list
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    input_list : list
        The list to get the adjacent indices from
    index_y : int
        The y index of the index to get the adjacent indices from
    index_x : int
        The x index of the index to get the adjacent indices from
    return_as : Literal['index', 'value'], optional
        The type to return the adjacent indices as, by default 'index'

    Returns
    -------
    list
        The adjacent indices of the given index in the given list (as the given type)
    """
    # Get the y and x size of the list
    size_y, size_x = len(input_list), len(input_list[0])

    adjacent_indice_lst = []

    # Iterate over the y range
    for y in range(index_y-1, index_y+2):
        # Iterate over the x range
        for x in range(index_x-1, index_x+2):
            # Check if the y and x are in range
            # Also check if the y and x are not the same as the index
            if y < 0 or y >= size_y or x < 0 or x >= size_x or (y == index_y and x == index_x):
                continue
            
            if return_as == 'index':
                # Add the index to the adjacent_indiece_lst
                adjacent_indice_lst.append((y, x))

            elif return_as == 'value':
                # Add the value to the adjacent_indice_lst
                adjacent_indice_lst.append(input_list[y][x])

    return adjacent_indice_lst
```

### Without comments

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal

def get_adjacent_indices(input_list:list, index_y:int, index_x:int, return_as:Literal['index', 'value']='index') -> list:
    size_y, size_x = len(input_list), len(input_list[0])

    adjacent_indice_lst = []
    for y in range(index_y-1, index_y+2):
        for x in range(index_x-1, index_x+2):
            if y < 0 or y >= size_y or x < 0 or x >= size_x or (y == index_y and x == index_x):
                continue
            
            if return_as == 'index':
                adjacent_indice_lst.append((y, x))
            elif return_as == 'value':
                adjacent_indice_lst.append(input_list[y][x])
    return adjacent_indice_lst
```

### Outputs

```py
test_list = ['1234', '6789', 'abcd', 'efgh']

print(get_adjacent_indices(test_list, 1, 1)) # [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
print(get_adjacent_indices(test_list, 2, 1, 'value')) # ['6', '7', '8', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
print(get_adjacent_indices(test_list, 0, 0, 'value')) # ['2', '6', '7']
```