# Given a 2D array, find out if a given node is surrounded

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array where each digit represents a different color, I want to be able to find out if a given node in the array is surrounded completely by one color.  For example, in the 2d array below, I want to be able to confirm that the node at [3][3] is completely surrounded by the color represented by "1".  Is there an existing common algorithm that accomplishes this?

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}}
```

EDIT: Sorry I am not asking about whether the target node is immediately surrounded.  I am asking about whether if you move out from the target node, you can reach the edge of the array without crossing over the boundary color.

My current code is the following, but it's not quite working

```
let squaresChecked = []
let squareSurrounded = true
let boardSize = 15
let gameBoard = new Array(boardSize)
for(let i=0; i<gameBoard.length; i++){
 gameBoard[i] = Array(boardSize).fill('white')
}


checkSurrounded(x, y, boundaryColor){
    if(x >= boardSize || y >= boardSize || x < 0 || y < 0){
      squareSurrounded = false
      return
    }
    if(gameBoard[x][y] === boundaryColor){return}
    if(squaresChecked.includes(x + ' ' + y)){return}
    squaresChecked.push(x + ' ' + y)

    checkSurrounded(x+1, y, boundaryColor)
    checkSurrounded(x-1, y, boundaryColor)
    checkSurrounded(x, y+1, boundaryColor)
    checkSurrounded(x, y-1, boundaryColor)
}
```

Comment: `if(array[2][3]==1 && array[3][2]==1 && array[4][3]==1 && array[3][4]==1){it's surrounded}`

Comment: This question seems to fall into "find a cell's neighbors".  Is your matrix index starting at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've already got that tries to solve this situation? We try not to do people's work for them but we're happy to help when you're stuck with a specific question.

Comment: @DanielHao, no I meant [3][3] with indices starting at 0.

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657128/how-to-access-the-adjacent-cells-of-each-elements-of-matrix-in-python/65849982#65849982

Answer (score 0):

This should check for top, left, right, bottom for given cell at row,col in 2D array if surrounded by var surroundedBy (1).

```
row = 2
col = 2
arr = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]]
surroundedBy = 1
if(arr[row-1][col] ===surroundedBy && arr[row+1][col] === surroundedBy && arr[row][col - 1] === surroundedBy && arr[row][col + 1] === surroundedBy) {
     console.log('surrounded');
}else{
      console.log('not surrounded');
}
```